# How to localize and show a list of data for different languages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an XML file contains names of countries, another file contains the same content in another language.

I want to do binding here, show for french the french file, for another languages its own file and so on.. in a long list control

1. How can I add these files and where (Resources folder?)
2. how can I name the files, I should follow a specific pattern(like `countries.en.xml` , `countries.fr.xml`?
3. and is the concept like using key/value in AppResources, which uses the correct culture automatically?

Sorry I know the question is really basic, but I couldn't stand up for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one of two options. The first is to simply put the content of the xml within the AppResources file itself. This is probably the best option. This would allow you to bind to the values just as you would any other string

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.America, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
```

The second option is to place the content in the xml and load them through code. You could do this through the provided LocalizedStrings class. You could expose a Countries property that loads once based on the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
private static IDictionary<string, Country> _countries;

public IDictionary<string, Country> Countries
{
    get
    {
        if (_countries == null)
        {
            var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            var name = culture.Name;
            if (name == "en-us")
            {
                // load
            }
            else
            {
                // load
            }
        }
        return _countries;
    }
}
```

This would allow you to bind as such

```
Text="{Binding Path=Countries[America], Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"/>
```